# jslint configuration | passing globals

Tags: javascript, jslint

How do I alert jshint that I have globals, i.e. name them.  I know you can do this, but I don't recall the syntax.

I defined a global here like this

```
(function(){window.glob1 = local_var;})()
```

and use later like this: ( a different IIFE )

```
(function(){glob1 // does something})()
```

jshint is saying it was used before it was defined.

It's not a flag, there is actually a way to list global variables by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean the syntax

```
 /* global window, console, jQuery */
```

... at the beginning of the each JS file?

Comment: Hi Hiro: why did you change the syntax of the answer? I think the comma separated form is more commonly used.

Comment: I thought it was more readable, but you can change it back if you prefer.

Comment: how come?  I like having all my whitespace set ... i don't think jslint does that?

Comment: Hmm. Might be an old problem fixed in the current versions. Removing the note.