# How can I stop jshint errors in my web file for globals?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a protractor test script file that looks like this:

```
var TestPage = function () {

    this.detailsTab = element(by.id('detailsTab'));
    ..
```

It's giving me a lot of errors saying `element` and `by` are not defined. Is there a way I can stop all these hint errors from appearing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jslint configuration | passing globals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574203/jslint-configuration-passing-globals)

Comment: this question is specific about protractor, you should update the title.  how about `how can i remove jshint warnings about valid global  variables in protractor`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [protractor tutorial page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md) you can see that these globals are created by Protactor:

> This uses the globals `element` and `by`, which are also created by
>   Protractor.

So you need a way of telling JSHint about these globals. You can do this in your configuration for JSHint. http://www.jshint.com/docs/

**Inline Configuration Method**

One of the ways JSHint can be configured is by using adding special inline comments. Below is an excerpt taken from the JSHint docs page that describes how to specify global using the inline comment configuration method.

> globals - A directive for telling JSHint about global variables that are defined
>   elsewhere. If value is `false` (default), JSHint will consider that
>   variable as read-only. Use it together with the `undef` option.

```
/* global MY_LIB: false */
```

**Update:** So for protractor the inline config would be:

```
/* global element */
/* global by */
```

or as suggested by @runTarm this condensed syntax will also work:

```
/* global element, by */
```

**Config File Method**

You can also configure JSHint by using configuration files. Check the [documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) for the different ways to specify the config file. From the docs page we the following excerpt that explains how to write the file to specify a global variable.

> Configuration file is a simple JSON file that specifies which JSHint
>   options to turn on or off. For example, the following file will enable
>   warnings about undefined and unused variables and tell JSHint about a
>   global variable named `MY_GLOBAL`.

```
{
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "predef": [ "MY_GLOBAL" ]
}
```

Comment: So just to clarify can you show what the global inline would like like for protractor. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @SamanthaJ You need to add `/* global element */` and `/* global by */` I also updated the answer.

Comment: `/* global element, by */` would do as well

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example .jshint file with the globals being removed:

```
{
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "camelcase": true,
    "curly": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "multistr": true,
    "globals": {
        "after": false,
        "afterEach": false,
        "angular": false,
        "before": false,
        "beforeEach": false,
        "browser": false,
        "describe": false,
        "expect": false,
        "inject": false,
        "it": false,
        "jasmine": false,
        "spyOn": false,
        "Kinetix": false,
        "$": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### the actual .jshintrc configuration for protractor

if you want to get rid of jshint warnings for protractor, updating .jshintrc is the best approach.  adding global overrides per file is rather tedious.

add the following to your `.jshintrc` file (you should be able to add a .jshintrc file in the directory that contains your tests rather than the root/all of your source)

.jshintrc:

```
  {
   ... your other jshint stuff ...
   "jasmine": true,
   "mocha": true,
   "globals": {
     "angular": false,
     "browser": false,
     "inject": false,
     "_": false,
     "driver": false,
     "protractor": false,
     "browser": false,
     "$": false,
     "$$": false,
     "element": false,
     "by": false,
     "list": false
    }
  }
```

what this does: (you may not need jasmine/mocha depending on how you wrote your tests)

- jasmine is required for things like `expect`
- mocha is required for things like `beforeEach` -
- the globals are other things that protractor defines on as globals - see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L152